# Multi-server NextJS building inconsistent static js files under the same build id

Tags: node.js, next.js, build, production

I am deploying a nextjs service on cloud with application load balancing, applying on 3 Linux instances.

I am doing production build on each instance, I found out that there is 50% chance that the static files have a different filename hash, i.e. in /.next/static/chunk/, in the format of name-[hash].js.

Sometimes I get 219-2df97cdbd67046ff.js, while sometimes I get 219-5cf092bac20000d6.js.
While using a round-robin application load balancing, I need all static files to be consistent.

I have already tried fixing it by the same build id, but the static js file name hash may still be different.

Interestingly, sometimes the hash can be the same across all builds purely by luck, and the whole web app is running smoothly.

Does anyone has any idea about this? Is NextJS building static JS with time information so the content and the filename is not always the same? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I find that the build will have the same results acrossing instances whenever I start building AT THE SAME MINUTE.